# Songs are in the wrong order in the Music app (macOS only)

Tags: music.app

A bunch of albums have their songs show up in the wrong order, when I look at them in the Music app (macOS Big Sur 11.0.1, although this has been happening in older versions too). When I look at the same albums in the iOS Music app, they show up just fine. I use Apple Music.

I can't figure out what's going on. When I right click -> Get Info, everything looks fine, the song order is set just right for all songs in these albums.

Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not going to ask that because it is very similar, but I am also experiencing similar issues with adding songs to my library via the `+` sign on Mac. Further it seems like some songs that **definitely** were in my library before the BigSur upgrade are not anymore. Apple needs to fix this ASAP!